# hidden element dojo parsing

Tags: dojo

How can I avoid the dojo parser showing a hidden element after it's parsed?

```
<input type="checkbox" dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" style="display:none">
```

When the dojo parser is done, the `dijit` checkbox will be shown, but the input "inside" it, will still be hidden. I want the dojo parser to create the `dijit` checkbox, but keep it hidden.

Comment: I did not see the checkbox show with dojo 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a limitation of how Dijit works... it's the construction of the widget that's doing this, not the parser per se.  The style element gets mapped to the INPUT element, so there is no way to do this short of instantiating the widget directly and hiding it before placing it in the DOM.  Updating the style after the parser does its thing would probably result in some unwanted redraws.

Comment: Ugly hack, but it seems to be the only way around this... Thanks anyway (:

Answer (score 0):

I use dijit.layout.BorderContainer with style="height:100%;width:100%;visibility:hidden" and it's working fine for me.